# Sort a ruby hashmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hashmap

I have the following line of code

```
<% map = options_for_select(User.all.map {|u| [u.first_name+" "+u.last_name, u.id]}) %>
```

which grabs the first and last name of a user and submits its ID in a  form. Now I have added a few users and they are not in alphabetical order. How can I sort this map by first name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be...

```
   <% map = options_for_select(User.all.map {|u| [u.first_name+" "+u.last_name, u.id]}.sort) %>
```

Comment: damn yeah... i tried `.sort` after the bracket... sorry new to rails... Thanks man!

Comment: In my experience (well I started learning Rails, without a clue of Ruby...) learning Ruby solves majority of issues we face when developing a Rails application. So try that approach, it saves a lot of our time and makes us even more curious about Ruby.

Comment: works great!
yeah I am currently working my way through Lynda's ruby course. The issue is that sometimes it seems odd which order to place methods in. i.e. where to put the sort here..

Comment: Killerpixler Be careful on using that line just like that on your view. It works, but you're violating several Rails best practices at the same time :) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156400/3324188)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `order` to get the rows already ordered from the database:

```
<% map = options_for_select(User.all.order(:first_name).map {|u| [u.first_name+" "+u.last_name, u.id]}) %>
```

Comment: Probably the better approach here, likely to be more efficient especially if the database has an index on the attribute used for sorting.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Yes very true. There are better approaches (for anything). But they are better only when proved. How would you prove that? I am curious to see the proof for I am willing to adopt it.

Comment: @Bala If the database has an index on the `name` attribute it already knows the order (an index is always sorted as far as I know, otherwise it's kinda pointless), so it can retrieve the data from disk in sorted order and return that. Your Hash has to be sorted afterwards by comparing all elements to each other so should be slower. Probably not noticeable on small amounts of data but sorting at the database level should be preferred if possible. I'm not sure about the case without an index though, might not matter too much.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers what if the database is of NoSQL such as Neo4j?  The OP did not pose those constraints.  Thinking too much some times restrict simple solutions. Do you agree?

Comment: @Bala I don't think Rails actually supports NoSQL databases for Activerecord models, it only works with relational databases I believe. Perhaps there are workarounds for it. Besides, I know there are NoSQL databases which support indexing, such as MongoDB. Anyway, I wasn't saying your answer was wrong, just pointing out using order at the database level is most likely the same or faster.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: I wanted to learn from your approach, that is why I posed those comments. There are no right or wrong, it always depends on how we see it.  By the way, Neo4j supports indexing...(...and I do not belong to Neo4j in any way....)

Answer (score 1):

You should never use queries on the views. You should use views only for presentation, and all the logic on the Models and or the Controllers.

Also, respecting [Fat Models, Skinny Controllers Best Practice](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/):

> In practice, this can require a range of different types of refactoring, but it all comes down to one idea: by moving any logic that isn’t about the response (for example, setting a flash message, or choosing whether to redirect or render a view) to the model (instead of the controller), not only have you promoted reuse where possible but you’ve also made it possible to test your code outside of the context of a request.

Finally, in this case it's best to use a scope to reuse it later.

Use a scope on User model, and have a `name` method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :order_by_name, ->(first_name, last_name) { order("#{first_name} ASC, #{ last_name} ASC") }

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

If you're calling your line from `users/index`, create an instance variable to load the users collection like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.order_by_name
  end
end
```

Then you would call on the view using `options_from_collection_for_select` like this:

```
<% map = options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do both the CONCAT and ORDER in the Database for performance reasons

```
User.select("CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name), u.id").order("u.first_name")
```

This `User.all.map` could be a bottleneck of your application